# Update data without relying direct on the connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, api, .net-4.0, schedule

I have an application that once started will get some initial data from my database and after that some functions may update or insert data to it.

Since my database is not on the same computer of the one running the application and I would like to be able to freely move the application server around, I am looking for a more flexible way to insert/update/query data as needed.

I was thinking of using an website API on a separated thread on my application with some kinda of list where this thread will try to update the data every X minutes and if a given entry is updated it will be removed from the list.

This way instead of being held by the database queries and the such the application would run freely queuing what has to be update/inserted etc

The main point here is so I can run the functions without worrying about connectivity issues to the database end, or issues related, since all the changes are queued to be updated on it.

Is this approach ok ? bad ? are the better recommendations for this scenario ?

Comment: In addition to @Alexei answer you might want to look at WCF data services.

Comment: Dustin unhappily I can't use WCF as of now but I am considering it for an next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On "can access DB through some web server instead of talking directly to DB server": yes this is very common and recommended approach. It is much easier to limit set of operations exposed through custom API (web services, REST services, ...) than restrict direct communication with DB.

On "sync on separate thread..." - you need to figure out what are requirements of the synchronization. Delayed sync may be ok if you don't need to know latest data and not care if updates from client are commited to storage immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot alexei glad to know I'm not so off of the path. I was planning to sync the data with 2 basis, 1 every X minutes and re-queing failed data.